# Who is this decorated WWI Italian Army General?

Tags: identification, world-war-one, italy, italian, army

This has been a tough one. I'm trying to identify who this is. He's an Italian General, and a highly decorated one, with four medals of valour, two crosses of war merit (Croce al Merito di Guerra), and a French Croix de Guerre. Plus a minimum 16 years of service cross, and numerous high royal awards. He also has WW1 medals representing the 1st, 3rd, 8th, and 10th Army Divisions. My ability to decipher his autograph has failed. It's dedicated to a "Mrs. Kirby" (I think) and dated 1924.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I thank you.

> [image]

Comment: Apparently dedicated to two ladies - _à madame et à Mrs (?)Kirby, affectueusement_ - but the signature is undecipherable.

Answer (score 11):

Pretty clearly matches the face of [Diaz Armando Vittorio](https://www.storiaememoriadibologna.it/diaz-armando-vittorio-515235-persona)

[image]

> ... immediately afterwards agreed to enter Mussolini's first government as Minister of War, appearing above all as a guarantee for the monarchy and the army. As minister he tried to complete the reorganization of the army after the demobilization process and the Fiume shocks, a task that Diaz considered accomplished in 1924, when he retired to private life. On 4 November of the same year he was appointed Marshal of Italy together with Luigi Cadorna. He died in Rome on 29 February 1928.
> Francesco Annichiarico

Comment: He replaced Cadorna after the 12th Battle of the Isonzo.

Comment: @njuffa: To my eye, he looks older above than in OP. The medals are also arranged differently; which combined with the jeweled collar above suggests he is older, and higher ranking, above than in the OP. Beyond that - ask another question. The portrait subject has been, as requested, identified.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens also, in the first picture he has only one band on his cap, while in the second, he has four.

Comment: Any particular reason for the unusual form of his name? In an alphabetical list, I’d expect to see ‘Diaz, Armando Vittorio’, but normally I’d expect ‘Armando Vittorio Diaz’ (or more commonly just ‘Armando Diaz’).

Comment: @Davidw really, 12th battle? Sure, the Isonzo valley is heavily fortified, but did they really fight twelve and more times at the same place in a single war? Or is it, say, Italy's twelfth battle of the war, which happened to be at the Isonzo?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It appears that "Armando" is his first name, and "Diaz" his normal citizen's surname. The "duca de la Vittoria" looks like a title. If you look at his plaques in the site Pieter linked, the last one is signed "A. Diaz". I have no idea if he also has the middle name "Vittorio" or if the site attached a short form of his title after his alphabetized name.

Comment: @rumtscho _Duce della Vittoria_ (‘Duke of Victory’) is a title conferred upon him in 1922. Some sources list his birth name as Armando Vittorio Diaz, while others just give it as Armando Diaz. I have no idea if he did actually have that middle name or not, but that doesn’t really matter here – it’s the specific form “Diaz Armando [Vittorio]” that just looks odd to me, an Italian name essentially written as though it were a Hungarian/Chinese/Japanese name.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that's just how this specific site has chosen to organize its pages about people - by titling them in alphabetical order by surname. See https://www.storiaememoriadibologna.it/archivio/persone/. It appears to be a taxonomist's quirk, not something specific to this general.

Comment: @rumtscho I figured the immediate reason was probably that website, but I didn’t know if it was based on some established military or historiographic practice I wasn’t aware of.

Comment: @Davidw: You are confusing the succession to position of Italian Army Chief of Staff with the post-war title *Marshal of Italy* awarded simultaneously to both by Mussolini in 1924.

Comment: @rumtscho: oh yes, [there were no less than twelve Isonzo Battles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battles_of_the_Isonzo). Because of the terrain (the rest of this front was heavily mountainous, strongly fortified, highly inaccessible, and not conducive to exploiting an eventual victory), this was pretty much the only area where the Italians and the Austro-Hungarians could fight. At the German-French front, there could be battles at different places (Marne, Somme, Verdun etc.), not so much here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's not an uncommon way of arranging names in Italy, especially in a bureaucratic setting (e.g. when doing a roll call).

Comment: The signature on the OP's photo doesn't look like any combination of Armando Diaz or Vittoria. I see something that looks like it ends in _alecio_.

Comment: @shoover: Without a readable inscription, the signature might be the photographer's. Drawing inferences from that is rather outlandish.